SQLite - set only the correct returned result from a joined table
Quite new to all of this..
I have two tables (names simplified)
PersonTable



PersonID
NamePrefix
NameSuffix




1
Null
Null


2
Null
Null


3
Sir
Nul


4
Null
Null



FactTable



FactType
OwnerID
FactDetail




24
3
(irrelevant)


42
2
Capt.


42
3
Hon.


36
3
Lord of Somewhere



Clearly I need to run 2 separate UPDATE queries
One to update the NamePrefix where FactType = 42, and
One to update the NameSuffix where FactType = 36
Each PersonID in the FactTable may have none, one, or more than one entry, but usually only one for each Fact Type (unless there's an error somewhere in the data - which I'm not worried about for now)
What I tried
what I am running
UPDATE PersonTable
SET NamePrefix = Trim( PersonTable.NamePrefix || " " || 
(
SELECT  FactTable.FactDetails
    FROM PersonTable
    INNER JOIN FactTable 
    ON PersonTable.PersonID = FactTable.OwnerID 
    WHERE FactTable.FactType='42'
    AND FactTable.OwnerID = PersonTable.OwnerID
)
);

What I am expecting to see in the Table after the first run (Fact Type='42')



PersonID
NamePrefix
NameSuffix




2
Capt.
Null


3
Hon Sir
Null



and What I am expecting to see in the Table after running the second run (Fact Type='36')



PersonID
NamePrefix
NameSuffix




2
Capt.
Null


3
Hon Sir
Lord of Somewhere



HOWEVER
The result I am getting is that All instances of the Person Table are being populated by the first matching record in the FactTable (that = 42) so everyone has a prefix of CAPT whether they have any entries in the Fact Table or not.
Yet, when I run only the Select Part,
SELECT  PersonTable.OwnerID, FactTable.FactDetails --(I need that extra first field in there to check the right person)
    FROM PersonTable
    INNER JOIN FactTable 
    ON PersonTable.PersonID = FactTable.OwnerID 
    WHERE FactTable.FactType='42'
    AND FactTable.OwnerID = PersonTable.OwnerID

I get a correct list of only those people in the PersonTable, having a corresponding fact, of the correct type (42)
As I have said, I am new to this so probably a very rookie mistake that I just can't see. I have tried several snippets from various to get to this point

The intended result you have shown seems to be slightly incorrect. According to your description and logic, it must be Sir Hon., not Hon Sir. I assumed in my answer that your description is correct, but not the result table in your question. Please let me know if it's vice versa.

Note: The solution shown in this answer requires SQLite version 3.33.0 or later.
It would be simpler to use the UPDATE FROM syntax rather than a complex subquery with JOIN.
In the WHERE clause, all necessary conditions can be set.
In your case, you say PersonTable.PersonID = Fact.OwnerID and also check the FactType.
So, the first update command will be:
UPDATE PersonTable
  SET NamePrefix = TRIM(COALESCE(PersonTable.NamePrefix, '') || ' ' || Fact.FactDetail)
FROM (SELECT FactDetail, OwnerID, FactType FROM FactTable) AS Fact
WHERE 
  PersonTable.PersonID = Fact.OwnerID
  AND Fact.FactType = 42;

and the second one:
UPDATE PersonTable
  SET NameSuffix = Fact.FactDetail || ' ' || TRIM(COALESCE(PersonTable.NameSuffix, ''))
FROM (SELECT FactDetail, OwnerID, FactType FROM FactTable) AS Fact
WHERE 
  PersonTable.PersonID = Fact.OwnerID
  AND Fact.FactType = 36;

Note: I added a COALESCE around the PersonTable.NamePrefix because otherwise, it will stay NULL if it was already NULL before.
After running both update commands, the person table will look like this:



PersonID
NamePrefix
NameSuffix




1
null
null


2
Capt.
null


3
Sir Hon.
Lord of Somewhere


4
null
null



See this sample fiddle

Thanks, For some reason it spits an an error in the FROM statement.
Recreated the entire fiddle, and each part worked.

3.15.0  Works in SQLiteExpert, but not in SQLite Studio

You should urgently upgrade to a new version. The version 3.15.0 was released in 2016. The syntax with UPDATE FROM I have shown in my answer was introduced to SQLite in version 3.33.0, in 2020. So even this is already four years old. See https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html I will mention this in my answer. As said, I recommend to upgrade. If this is not possible for you, please edit your question and add your version there, then people might think about a solution for your obsolete version.

I don't even find a fiddle for this old version (3.15), so I can't try out other solutions in your version. Maybe someone has installed such a version on their system and can help you, far simpler would be to upgrade.
